# Next.js sitemap with url paramters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sitemap

I am trying to create a sitemap for the the project I'm working on and currently using `next-sitemap` to generate. The problem with this approach and pretty much another solution I found is that the sitemap is generated for the pages that are created during build time.

My use-case requires adding URL parameters in the sitemap as well which do not generate new pages during build time.

This is also the closest approach I think that should work but I will need to access the `JSON` data for each dynamic page generated during build time.

```js
/pages/sitemap.xml.js

const staticPages = fs
    .readdirSync("pages")
    .filter((staticPage) => {
      return ![
        "_app.js",
        "_document.js",
        "_error.js",
        "sitemap.xml.js",
      ].includes(staticPage);
    })
    .map((staticPagePath) => {
      return `${baseUrl}/${staticPagePath}`;
    });

  const sitemap = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
      ${staticPages
        .map((url) => {
          return `
            <url>
              <loc>${url}</loc>
              <lastmod>${new Date().toISOString()}</lastmod>
              <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
              <priority>1.0</priority>
            </url>
          `;
        })
        .join("")}
    </urlset>
  `
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently Next.js saves all the `JSON` of each dynamic page at `.next/server/pages/dynamicPage` and we can use `node fs` to read the files and then parse them. This solved the issue.

So the approach which worked for my use-case:

```js
 const staticPages = fs
    .readdirSync('.next/server/pages/scheme')
    .filter((file) => path.extname(file).toLowerCase() === '.json');

  const schemeFiles = ['https://schemes.openbudgetsindia.org'];
  staticPages.forEach((staticPagePath) => {
    const schemeName = staticPagePath.split('.')[0];
    schemeFiles.push(
      `https://schemes.openbudgetsindia.org/scheme/${schemeName}`
    );
    const schemeObj = JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync(`.next/server/pages/scheme/${staticPagePath}`, 'utf8')
    );
    const { indicators } = schemeObj.pageProps.scheme.metadata;
    indicators.forEach((indicator) =>
      schemeFiles.push(
        `https://schemes.openbudgetsindia.org/scheme/${schemeName}?indicator=${indicator}`
      )
    );
  });
```

After that, simply create the `XML` data:

```js
  const sitemap = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
      ${staticPages
        .map((url) => {
          return `
            <url>
              <loc>${url}</loc>
              <lastmod>${new Date().toISOString()}</lastmod>
              <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
              <priority>1.0</priority>
            </url>
          `;
        })
        .join("")}
    </urlset>

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.write(sitemap);
  res.end();
```